# Are living insects in my laptop dangereous?

Tags: laptop

My laptop become a house of Ants, Every time I am seeing some ants creeping to my laptop.

Do the ants cause any problem to my laptop? How can I get rid of them?

Comment: Do you know how these ants got in the laptop?

Comment: Compressed air too, should blow the ants out, (do it in the garden), and it will hopefully help blow the eggs too. Also, consider calling a pest controller - if not for a proper job, then for advice.  And keep your eyes open! How can ants get into your laptop unless there are ants around it. Maybe you have ants in your house! And your bed.. you might want to look into that.  If you've been using the laptop on the toilet, the cause might be ants in your pants.

Comment: I would just let them do their thing... haven't you seen Pi?  You could be on the brink of some fantastic discovery!

Comment: Sounds like you've got buggy hardware.... Sorry couldn't help it.

Comment: Have you considered buying one of [these stickers](http://i.imgur.com/SSxHG.jpg)?

Comment: For your amusement: [Ants in a Scanner](http://www.neatorama.com/2010/11/10/ants-in-a-scanner/).

Answer (score 4):

I would take the laptop apart as far as possible (remove the keyboard, etc.).  It's likely you spilled something sweet into it and the ants are prospecting for food. You might want to remove all the keyboard caps (if your system supports this) and thoroughly blow out every speck of dust (and food crumb) and be sure everything is thoroughly dry. If the keyboard is sticky, you might have to totally disconnect it, clean it with distilled or deionized water and **dry it completely before putting it back.**

Answer (score 2):

Yes, pests including Ants, BedBugs, etc do cause problems for any electronics, include laptops. They can die in the laptop causing problems, as well as possibly nibbling on components...

First, did you spill anything on or near the laptop? Try wiping down the outside of the laptop with an antibacterial wipes. Get some ant traps, and place them around the laptop.

Remove the battery, and power cord. Leave your laptop off, and then wait. See what happens, but unless your willing to disassemble your laptop, or have someone else do it, your going to have to resort to external traps of some kind.

I would almost suggest placing the laptop in a large 1 gallon ziplock, but I'm afraid the ants will be killed inside the laptop...

Comment: in addition to possibly trying to eat/dig through the components they will impede the ability of laptop to dissipate heat

Comment: A dilute solution of vinegar (1 part vinegar, 3 parts water) will wash away the scent trails ants leave for each other.